# array of strings dynamically allocated in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, dynamic

I have a problem:
   I have to read a text (from stdin) and I know how many lines the text has (N), it will be something like that:
sentence1 (enter)
sentence2 (enter)
sentence3 (enter) \0
I don't know how many characters are in every sentence (the number will be different). Please help

Answer (score 1):

You are reading lines of unknown length, but you know there are N lines.

```
char *lines[N]; // the array of pointers to your lines
int i = 0;
```

to read each line you can declare a big array of chars if you have some idea how long the longest sentence might be:

```
char *buffer;  
buffer = calloc(1000, sizeof(char)); // An arbitrary size. I made it up.
```

Then use fgets() to read from the file into buffer. fgets() will read up the next newline or EOF, whichever comes first.

Then put the address of your malloc'd space into your array of pointers:

```
lines[i] = buffer;
```

The downside of this is a lot of wasted space in the sentences. One way around it would be allocate another char array *after* reading the line from the file:

```
 char *sentence = calloc(strlen(buffer)+1, sizeof(char));
 strcpy(sentence, buffer, strlen(buffer));
```

Then put the address of the sentence into your array of pointers:

```
lines[i] = sentence;
```

This all falls apart if any of the sentences are longer than 1000 characters.